# Does SugarORM support joins?

Tags: java, android, join, orm, sugarorm

I can't seem to find it in any documentation but does SugarORM have built-in support for join queries?

On the SugarORM website under Query Builder (http://satyan.github.io/sugar/query.html) at the bottom it says "You can find a few more examples in the SelectTest.java class" but this leads to a 404, but I think I found the class here https://github.com/satyan/sugar/blob/master/library/src/test/java/com/orm/query/SelectTest.java but didn't see any joins.

Can anyone confirm or deny if joins are supported?